# Can I get variable from code.gs to my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I initially wanted to send automatic email once condition is met which I was able to implement. But I want the email to contain a more structured format and include an inline image from google drive. But when creating the html file, I'm curious if I can get a variable from code.gs and include it in html. This is how I envision it to look.

```
    <h2> Hello +name+ !</h2>
    <p>Your ticket number is +ticketNumber+ and you'll be participating under +company </p>
    <p><img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI"></p>
```

My initialcode.gs is below

```
    function sendMailEdit(e){
  
if (e.range.columnStart != 12 || e.value != "Yes") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
  var ticketNumber = rData[0][3];
  var company = rData[0][5];
  var name = rData[0][6];
  var email = rData[0][8];
  
  
  var msg = name +"Your payment has been verified. Your ticket number is " +ticketNumber+ ".Participating under " +company
  

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Swing Fore A Cause", msg)
  Logger.log(msg);

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing HTML and script and your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hi yes, I'm just wondering if I can customised certain lines of html. For example: In the header, I want the name of the person to be included so maybe I can use the variable name in the code.gs ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send an email by giving `name` to your showing HTML.
- So, in your goal, you want to send an email with the HTML body.

In this case, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 12 || e.value != "Yes") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
  var ticketNumber = rData[0][3];
  var company = rData[0][5];
  var name = rData[0][6];
  var email = rData[0][8];
  var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your ticket number is ${ticketNumber} and you'll be participating under ${company}</p><p><img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI"></p>`;
  var msg = name + "Your payment has been verified. Your ticket number is " + ticketNumber + ".Participating under " + company
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Swing Fore A Cause", msg, { htmlBody: html });
  Logger.log(msg);
}
```

- In this case, when the email client of the user can see the HTML email, `html` is shown.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: @Lyrien Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `can I insert a specified height and length here?`, in this case, how about using `width` or `height` like `<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI" width="200" height="200">`? In this case, both width and height are set. If you want to keep the aspect ratio, please set `width` or `height` like `<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI" width="200">`.

Comment: @Lyrien I confirmed that your 1st question was resolved. But, did my answers for your 2nd question show you the results what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.